How do I take a screenshot of the current frame in CapCut?
How do I take a screenshot of the current video frame in the desktop version of the video editor CapCut?


You can set a keyboard shortcut for "Export still frame" in the shortcuts menu.

Click the "Shortcut" button on the top menubar
Go to the "Basic" tab
Click the space for "Export still frame" and choose a button combination. (I chose Shift+S)
Save changes


